# click event not firing in IE11

Tags: javascript, onclick, filepicker

I have this js file:

```
function fireClick(node){
    if ( document.createEvent ) {
        var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initEvent('click', true, false);
        node.dispatchEvent(evt);
    } else if( document.createEventObject ) {
        node.fireEvent('onclick') ;
    } else if (typeof node.onclick == 'function' ) {
        node.onclick();
    }
}

function selectAvatar()
{

    var fileSelector = document.createElement('input');
    fileSelector.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    fileSelector.setAttribute('accept', "image/gif, image/jpeg");



    fileSelector.onchange = function(event) {
        var fileList = fileSelector.files;
        //alert(fileList.length);
        if (fileList.length==0) return;
        reader.readAsDataURL(fileList[0]);
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var dataURL = reader.result;
        //alert(dataURL);
        var container = document.getElementById("avatart-container-div");
        var backgroundIMgString = 'url("'+dataURL+'")';
        container.style.backgroundImage=backgroundIMgString;
    }
    fireClick(fileSelector);
}
```

which is supposed to open programatically a file picker to select an imgae. While this works on FF and chrome, this does NOT work on IE (11 is my version). The picker itself doesn't show up. Tried debugging line by line but everything seems fine (no errors or exceptions). Any have an idea what might be the problem?

Comment: By filepicker, do you mean `input[type="file"]`? IE can have some strange security restrictions when it comes to hidden file inputs, but there are workarounds. Is the filepicker hidden and if it is, what happens when you un-hide it?

Comment: Yes, I do mean `input[type="file"]`. As you can see, it is not added to the DOM at all. Will try to see what will happen.

Comment: Ah this is because you're just creating the element, not adding it to the DOM, for example to add it to the body you can use: `document.body.appendChild(fileSelector);`

Comment: Yeah, just tested it and it worked. Funny how this works on FF and chrome, but IE actually tries to protext you. Post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the comments:

You are actually only creating the element, **without** adding it to the DOM. You can add it to the DOM with: `document.body.appendChild(fileSelector);`

And in the selectAvatar function:

```
function selectAvatar()
{

    var fileSelector = document.createElement('input');
    fileSelector.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    fileSelector.setAttribute('accept', "image/gif, image/jpeg");

    document.body.appendChild(fileSelector);

    // do stuff
}
```

Also здрасти